# Retrieve the list of Thread(not ProcessThread) of the current application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

For a diagnostic tool, I would like to be able to retrieve the list of thread that is running for my current process.

I'm fully aware of the `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` but this returns me a list of "ProcessThread" which doesn't contains usefull information like thread name, call stack, ...

I fully understand that we cannot access this kind of information for another process than ours, but we should be able to retrieve those information for our current process, right?

I can't find a way to retrieve a list of Thread and not ProcessThread

Comment: This is a hard CLR limitation, you cannot iterate managed threads.  A debugger can, the iceberg that usually sinks that titanic is that a process cannot debug itself.  It must be another process.

Comment: Yes, but another process cannot see the other process thread's name no? So basically there is no way to have a list of all running threads?

Comment: Use Debug + Windows + Threads to see that a managed debugger can in fact see the thread name.  But you already shot that option with your requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately we have to do this kind of diagnostics on computers that doesn't have Visual studio installed :(

Comment: You don't need VS, you can write your own managed debugger.  The mdbg sample code shows how.  But you already shot that option with your requirements.

Comment: Which requirement ? Do you have any of that?

Comment: You can use the SOS(Sun Of Strike) debugger within Visual Studio or with WinDbg.

Comment: I need to create a part of software, it's for a deployed application